# Javascript Azure Function Output going to Dead Letter Queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a javascript Azure function that puts a message on a Service Bus queue:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
  var flatten = require('flat')

  var message = flatten(req.body);
  context.bindings.outputSbMsg = message;
  context.done();
};
```

When it runs via a Http trigger, the function completes successfully. However, the message ends up on the Dead Letter queue in Service Bus. I can't see any error in the logs. Where should I look to investigate what the cause of this is?

Comment: Can you check the DeadLetterReason and DeadLetterErrorDescription properties on messages in the dead letter queue? Find common reasons messages are moved to the dead letter queue at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues

Comment: That probably means there is somebody who processes those messages, and it crashes while doing so

Comment: How do I examine the dead letter queue? I can't see it in the portal, or in Service Bus Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Messages have a `deliveryCount` property on them, `maxDeliveryCount` is settable on a queue when the queue is created or being updated.

A message in the queue can only be received as many times as the `maxDeliveryCount`, i.e., once the delivery-count reaches the max-delivery-count, the message can't be received using a receiver for a queue since it will be moved to the deadletter queue.

If you want to receive the message after it is moved to the deadletter queue, you need to create a receiver for the deadletter queue.

Refer to this sample [processMessageFromDLQ.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/694c3b7f99151609e733fa7a2b5dbfce43816a34/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/javascript/advanced/processMessageFromDLQ.js#L31) which does the same with version 7.0.0 @azure/service-bus.

Moreover, you can also explicitly send messages to deadletter queue by specifying the reason, refer to the sample [movingMessagesToDLQ.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/694c3b7f99151609e733fa7a2b5dbfce43816a34/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/javascript/advanced/movingMessagesToDLQ.js#L61)

Version 7.0.0 has been recently published. Refer to the links below.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)